# ios - what is the correct way to add images to the bundle?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

I am trying to add these images:

```
1) Images for the UITabBar
2) The application icon
3) The launch icon
```

and I just want to make sure I get it right.  I googled for "adding images to ios bundle" but I seem to be getting some outdated results.  I am on xCode 4.3.3 and I am just wondering what are the right steps to add the images to the bundle. Is there a way to organize them on the file system, or its kind of a flat structure where I just add them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the image to the project. Then you choose the right hand Xcode pane, and click top left to get the file view, with the new image selected in the left pane. Scroll down, you see something like "Target Membership". Make sure the checkbox is selected for the image. Now it will be included in your bundle. you can get at it now with "[UIImage imageNamed:@"Foo.png"]" etc.

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: How do I actually add the image to the project? I did it once and it was a mess so I am not certain of the correct way.

Comment: If I just do File --> Add files to project_name ...is that considered adding it to the bundle?

Comment: Well, not really. Sometimes Xcode adds the file to your bundle sometimes not. The only way to be sure is to do as I said, open the file inspector, and verify that when you have selected a file, that your target has a checkbox showing it selected.

Comment: I think the issue is that my images are not Anti-aliased - would you know how to make the images Anti-aliased?

Comment: That is very unlikely. If you open them in Preview do they look OK? Antialiasing was really relevant back 20 years ago when you had bitmapped images that were made much bigger than original, then had these huge edges. Its very uncommon now. You need antialiasing when you have a bitmap image and you make it much bigger.